# Проблемма с webhook telegram. При регистрации webhook-а ошибка 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Пытаюсь настроить Вебхук для бота.
Строчка

```
 bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH,certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))
```

Выдает ошибку:

> The server returned HTTP 429 Too Many Requests.

Бот никаких сообщений не шлет! Тем более 30 штук в секунду...
Пробовал:

- зарегистрировать нового бота
- сделать новые сертификаты
- ждал сутки несколько раз

Не помогает.

Гуглил... Яндексил...
Сам Код (изначально работал!!!):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telebot
import cherrypy
import config

WEBHOOK_HOST = 'ХХ.ХХ.ХХ.ХХ'
WEBHOOK_PORT = 443  # 443, 80, 88 или 8443 (порт должен быть открыт!)
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = '192.168.0.2'  # На некоторых серверах придется указывать такой же IP, что и выше

WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = './webhook_cert.pem'  # Путь к сертификату
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = './webhook_pkey.pem'  # Путь к приватному ключу

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s:%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % (config.token)

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

# Наш вебхук-сервер
class WebhookServer(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        if 'content-length' in cherrypy.request.headers and \
                        'content-type' in cherrypy.request.headers and \
                        cherrypy.request.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json':
            length = int(cherrypy.request.headers['content-length'])
            json_string = cherrypy.request.body.read(length).decode("utf-8")
            update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
            # Эта функция обеспечивает проверку входящего сообщения
            bot.process_new_updates([update])
            return ''
        else:
            raise cherrypy.HTTPError(403)

# Хэндлер на все текстовые сообщения
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

# Снимаем вебхук перед повторной установкой (избавляет от некоторых проблем)
bot.remove_webhook()

 # Ставим заново вебхук
bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH,certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))

# Указываем настройки сервера CherryPy
cherrypy.config.update({
    'server.socket_host': WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
    'server.socket_port': WEBHOOK_PORT,
    'server.ssl_module': 'builtin',
    'server.ssl_certificate': WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT,
    'server.ssl_private_key': WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV
})

 # Собственно, запуск!
cherrypy.quickstart(WebhookServer(), WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, {'/': {}})
```

Comment: Также столкнулся с данной проблемой
добавление time.sleep(5) - решает проблему!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась после вставки паузы между строками:

```
bot.remove_webhook()

 time.sleep(5) # <<<ПАУЗА

 # Ставим заново вебхук
bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH,certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))
```

Видимо сервер телеграмма начали пугать два подряд быстрых обращения...
Минимальная пауза при которой код работает у меня -  0,74 сек.
Не забудьте

```
import time
```